# Missing profile images on top users page

Tags: bug, top-users

I just went to check out the [Top Users Page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) and was greeted by a *nearly* empty (of profile pics) page (nearly becasue a few do show up - and it's always the same few)

[image]

I just tried this on Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge.

Why is this happening?